# Using Exit button to close a winform program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an exit button on a winform that I want to use to close the program.  I have added the button name to the FormClosed property found in the events section of the winforms properties.   I thought that's all I had to do but when I click the button it does not close.  I looked at the code and while a handler is created, there is no code inside of it.  I don't know if that is correct or not.  Here is the code that was created in the Form.cs file:

```
private void btnExitProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

What else do I have to do?

Comment: "I have added the button name to the FormClosed property found in the events section of the winforms properties." Not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: He probably literally set the FormClosed-property in the designer to the name of the button that is used to close the Form, instead of using an event. (That's what I think)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
this.Close();
```

Closes the form programmatically.

Comment: If you write it with capital 'C'.. :D

Answer (score 14):

Remove the method, I suspect you might also need to remove it from your `Form.Designer`.

Otherwise: `Application.Exit();`

Should work.

That's why the designer is bad for you. :)

Comment: The drawback is that you will exit the entire application and not only the specified Form... :)

Answer (score 4):

The FormClosed Event is an Event that fires when the form closes. It is not used to actually close the form. You'll need to remove anything you've added there.

All you should have to do is add the following line to your button's event handler:

```
this.Close();
```

Comment: I have removed the information I had in that Event and added the code to the button event handler.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

We can close every window using `Application.Exit();`
Using this method we can close hidden windows also.

`private void btnExitProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          Application.Exit();
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Used Following Code

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit( )
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this little code in the event of the button:

```
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void btnExitProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015, added this to a menu for File -> Exit and in that handler put:

```
this.Close();
```

but the IDE said 'this' was not necessary.   Used the IDE suggestion with just `Close();` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to Close the form than you can use this.Close();
else if you want the whole application to be closed use Application.Exit();

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread();
}
```